# Maximum energy of photoelectrons

Tags: quantum-mechanics, photoelectric-effect

Why is the maximum energy of a photoelectron ${KE}_{max}=hf-W$ with $W$ being the work function ? I understand the Einstein-Planck relation but not how it fits into this equation.
Also, can the maximum energy of a beam of photoelectrons by calculated simply by multiplying the maximum energy of 1 photoelectron with the number of electrons, i.e. : $${KE}^n_{max}=n{KE}_{max}$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the work function is the energy required to remove the electron from the metal any additional energy the photon had will be converted into kinetic enrgy for the electron. The reason this is the max KE is because it is likely that the electron will loose KE through collisions etc. As for your second question yes that seems right to me.

Answer (score 0):

The electron begin to move out of the metal because it absorb amount of energy by the light , The energy of the light is given by 
$E=hf$.Suppose the amount of light absorbed by the electron is maximum then $E_e=hf$ , however then electron then escape as free electron from the metal as it reach enough $E_e=W$ , here some of the energy is used to escape from the metal given as $W$.Hence the when the electron start moving it only have $E_e=hf-W$.Suppose that the electron does not have any potential energy , then $E_e=KE$, that is by assuming the light is totally absorbed by the electron.